# Fetch geotag from uploaded images with Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

The idea: at the moment I have a script which watch for new images uploaded (from smartphone or tab) to a specific folder. The script moves image to some subfolder depending on image's name and append a row with corresponding data to specific spreadsheet.

Is it possible to fetch geo information from uploaded to Google Drive images (using smartphone) to put them to the spreadsheet? Searched over the API, but look there is no native function for that. Any 3rd-party solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to accomplish your task (to get geo-data of uploaded images) using GAS. There is no GAS service performing it and I am almost sure now there is no a 3rd-party solution for your task. A brief scheme for the task is the following

1. to traverse all files in the image folder.
2. to open every file by using the `DocsList.getFileById` method
3. to check if the file data has required MIME-type. I assume, that JPEG files are most wanted to you. They have the `image/jpeg` MIME-type. The [getContentType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_blob#getContentType) method of the BLOB class returns the data type.
4. for filtered files, to get the data by using the [BLOB.getBytes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_blob#getBytes) method, find in the data the EXIF-matadata (see bellow), parse it and get the geotags. The geo-info stored as metada inside of image file and usually has [EXIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) format. There is a number of Javascript libraries which are able to read EXIF of JPEG files, for instance, [this one](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/exif/exif.js). You can either write your own code which will perform this step or modify the exist library (if the library license permits it). The exist library modification should not be a problem.
5. to publish the retrieved geo-information to a spreadsheet.