# Upload an image to s document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am making a photo shooting contest, the competitor should register using a Google registration form, and upload his photo as well. I searched all over the internet to find a Google script that can be inserted into a form to upload a file using Google forms but could not find anything. Is it doable and how, and even if there can be other ideas to do such thing please let me know.

Comment: you got me wrong, the competitor is supposed to send me his image some how or upload it using the form im going to send him so it will be inserted in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Sory ,Can you see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898497/add-images-to-google-document-via-google-apps-script

Comment: and see this it may be usfull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370319/fetch-geotag-from-uploaded-images-with-google-apps-script

Comment: Re-reading your question I'm really wondering how these answers respond to your question ... I see no form, no file upload... just ways to insert image in a doc, wich was not even mentioned in your question. fyi, there are ways to call the picasa api to automatically create a picasa album with uploaded jpegs, including descriptions and authors... but since you seem to be satisfied with the present answers I'll leave it so.

Comment: I thought I could insert that script in somehow so i could get the image he inserted into a doc, and actually its working, but since you got a way so I can just upload it to the spreadsheet I would be glad if you helped, I could not find any useful link for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
function insertImage() {
  // Retrieve an image from the web.
  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo2w.png");

  // Create a document.
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById("");

  // Append the image to the first paragraph.
  doc.getChild(0).asParagraph().appendInlineImage(resp);
}
```

This link might help you as well :)

http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/class_documentapp_listitem.html#appendInlineImage

Happy coding !

Comment: Thank you, this will do, I will take it from here

Answer (score 10):

Here is a possible workflow **suggestion** that includes a form, a spreadsheet with responses and a doc with included images.

the form is [testable here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx1_5TIf3ndWudgLGPqs5-AHa-HUBe5qv5PWuInKzm52xHlq5l1/exec)

the spreadsheet is [viewable here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnqSFd3iikE3dGFsUWNpb08zVWx5YjFRckloZ0NFZGc&usp=sharing)

the doc is [viewable here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1E6yoROb52QjICsEbGVXIBdz8KhdFU_5gimWlJUbu8DI/edit?usp=sharing)

## **See EDIT 2**

*NOTES :*

1. *for now it works only with small images, I have to find a solution for that.* (see EDIT)
2. *the image insertion in spreadsheet doesn't work, I commented this line for now...*

And here is the full code, still a draft but I think it could be fully implemented if we find a solution to the aforementioned problems.

**EDIT :** *The size of the image is actually not relevant, I had success with images 4 times larger than the page size but in PNG format - it seems that **.png** is far more reliable in this context, that's after all good news!   btw, I can use indifferently the blob, the image file or the so-called thumbnail (which has the very same size as the original ;-) and I get always the same result.* I guess I'll have to post an question on that in another post :-D=

```
var submissionSSKey = '0AnqSFd3iikE3dGFsUWNpb08zVWx5YjFRckloZ0NFZGc';
var docurl = 'https://docs.google.com/document/d/1E6yoROb52QjICsEbGVXIBdz8KhdFU_5gimWlJUbu8DI/'
var listitems = ['Select a category','Portrait','Landscape','Nude','Night shots','Nature','Various']
var Panelstyle = {'background':'#dddddd','padding':'40px','borderStyle':'ridge','borderWidth':'15PX','borderColor':'#aaaaaa'}

function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Photography contest').setStyleAttribute('padding','50PX');
  var panel = app.createFormPanel().setStyleAttributes(Panelstyle).setPixelSize(400, 200);
  var title = app.createHTML('<B>Photography contest</B>').setStyleAttribute('color','grey').setStyleAttribute('fontSize','25PX');
  var grid = app.createGrid(6,2).setId('grid');
  var list1 = app.createListBox().setName('list1');
   for(var i in listitems){list1.addItem(listitems[i])}    
  var Textbox1 = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('TB1');
  var email = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('mail');
  var upLoad = app.createFileUpload().setName('uploadedFile');
  var submitButton = app.createSubmitButton('<B>Submit</B>'); 
  var warning = app.createHTML('Please fill in all fields').setStyleAttribute('background','#bbbbbb').setStyleAttribute('fontSize','20px');
  //file upload
  var cliHandler2 = app.createClientHandler()
  .validateLength(Textbox1, 1, 40).validateNotMatches(list1,'Select a category').validateEmail(email).validateNotMatches(upLoad, 'FileUpload')
  .forTargets(submitButton).setEnabled(true)
  .forTargets(warning).setHTML('Now you can submit your form').setStyleAttribute('background','#99FF99').setStyleAttribute('fontSize','12px');

  //Grid layout of items on form
  grid.setWidget(0, 1, title)
      .setText(1, 0, 'Category')
      .setWidget(1, 1, list1.addClickHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setText(2, 0, 'Name')
      .setWidget(2, 1, Textbox1.addClickHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setText(3, 0, 'Email')
      .setWidget(3, 1, email)
      .setText(4, 0, 'File Upload')
      .setWidget(4, 1, upLoad.addChangeHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setWidget(5, 0, submitButton)
      .setWidget(5, 1, warning);

  var cliHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(warning).setHTML('<B>PLEASE WAIT WHILE THE FILE IS UPLOADING<B>').setStyleAttribute('background','yellow');
  submitButton.addClickHandler(cliHandler).setEnabled(false);  
  panel.add(grid);
  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}


function doPost(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var ListVal = e.parameter.list1;
  var textVal = e.parameter.TB1;
  var Email = e.parameter.mail;
  var fileBlob = e.parameter.uploadedFile;
  var img = DocsList.createFile(fileBlob);
  try{
  var folder = DocsList.getFolder('photos');
  }catch(e){DocsList.createFolder('photos');var folder = DocsList.getFolder('photos')}
  img.addToFolder(folder);
  img.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder())
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(submissionSSKey).getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
//  var image = sheet.insertImage(img.getUrl(), 4, lastRow+1)
  var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 4).setValues([[ListVal,textVal,Email,img.getUrl()]]);
  var GDoc = DocumentApp.openByUrl(docurl)
  GDoc.appendTable([['Category : '+ListVal,'Name : '+textVal,'Email : '+Email]])
  var par = GDoc.appendParagraph('IMAGE PREVIEW')
  par.insertInlineImage(1, img.getThumbnail())
  GDoc.appendHorizontalRule();
  GDoc.saveAndClose();
  app.add(app.createLabel('Thank you for submitting'));
  return app
}
```

---

**EDIT 2 :** I have found solutions for (almost) all the issues... Here is the new code (only doPost part) that provides automatic image scaling for the doc preview.  Jpg, png or any other usual image format supported...and shows initial size + weight. I updated the online test form.

The spreadsheet issue has no solution for now, see [issue 145](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=145), so I use only a link to the image file but this one has no preview as stated in [issue 1239](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1239) but the document as it works now is a nice and useable workaround (in my opinion :-).

```
function doPost(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var ListVal = e.parameter.list1;
  var textVal = e.parameter.TB1;
  var Email = e.parameter.mail;
  var fileBlob = e.parameter.uploadedFile;
  var blob = fileBlob.setContentTypeFromExtension()
  var img = DocsList.createFile(blob);
  try{
  var folder = DocsList.getFolder('photos');
  }catch(e){DocsList.createFolder('photos');var folder = DocsList.getFolder('photos')}
  img.addToFolder(folder);
  img.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder());
  var weight = parseInt(img.getSize()/1000);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(submissionSSKey).getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 4).setValues([[ListVal,textVal,Email,img.getUrl()]]);
  var GDoc = DocumentApp.openByUrl(docurl)
  GDoc.appendTable([['Category : '+ListVal,'Name : '+textVal,'Email : '+Email]])
  var inlineI = GDoc.appendImage(img);
  var width = inlineI.getWidth();
  var newW = width;
  var height = inlineI.getHeight();
  var newH = height;
  var ratio = width/height
  Logger.log('w='+width+'h='+height+' ratio='+ratio);
  if(width>640){
  newW = 640;
  newH = parseInt(newW/ratio);
  }
  inlineI.setWidth(newW).setHeight(newH)
  GDoc.appendParagraph('IMAGE size : '+width+' x '+height+' (eventually) resized to '+newW+' x '+newH+' for PREVIEW ('+weight+' kB)   ');
  GDoc.appendHorizontalRule();
  GDoc.saveAndClose();
  app.add(app.createLabel('Thank you for submitting'));
  return app
}
```

Comment: to solve the spreadsheet lin knot working use the solution provided in the other post : code like this :`var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 4).setValues([[ListVal,textVal,Email,"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="+img.getId()]]);`   demo form updated, ss results ok from now ;-)

Comment: I am getting the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property "parameter" from undefined. (line 47, file "Code"). Any possible ways to fix this?

Comment: You are probably trying to run doPost on its own, this is not doable... you have to deploy this function as a webapp (save a version first) and use the provided url resulting from the webapp deployment.

Comment: Thanks, can you also explain what a docURL and submissionKey is? Sorry, I am naive here, I tried googling around but everything seems to be complicated to me.

Comment: This script is using a couple of deprecated services, at least one of them ceased working (DocsList) so maybe it's not a very good idea to use it now... anyway, I updated the code to make it work again for a while, new script available here : https://script.google.com/d/1N-aT8EmBf7T4ZdveeRFVYNsUGc1Gge2sXeuJ6FHogSsbe4FGTO_enx2h/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: For anyone reading this in this future, some tips to get it working: (1) docURL is the URL of the Google Doc you created, (2) submission key is the last part of the URL of the Google Sheet you created -- e.g. `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<submission key>/`, (3) make sure the sheet in your Google Sheet is named "Sheet1" or rename it in the code, and (4) use "publish as web app..." to get create the app and test.

Comment: To get the URLs to the Google Doc and Google Sheet, either look in your browsers address bar and ignore the "/edit" suffix, etc., or click the "Share" button and use the URL provided there instead.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to jfreake recent post I ended up solving all the issues, including show the images in the spreadsheet itself. 
Here is the final code I post in a separate answer for comfort and readbility.

```
var submissionSSKey = '0AnqSFd3iikE3dGFsUWNpb08zVWx5YjFRckloZ0NFZGc';
var docurl = 'https://docs.google.com/document/d/1E6yoROb52QjICsEbGVXIBdz8KhdFU_5gimWlJUbu8DI/'
var listitems = ['Select a category','Portrait','Landscape','Nude','Night shots','Nature','Various']
var Panelstyle = {'background':'#dddddd','padding':'40px','borderStyle':'solid','borderWidth':'10PX','borderColor':'#bbbbbb'}

function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Photography contest').setStyleAttribute('padding','50PX');
  var panel = app.createFormPanel().setStyleAttributes(Panelstyle).setPixelSize(400, 200);
  var title = app.createHTML('<B>Photography contest</B>').setStyleAttribute('color','grey').setStyleAttribute('fontSize','25PX');
  var grid = app.createGrid(6,2).setId('grid');
  var list1 = app.createListBox().setName('list1').setWidth('130');
   for(var i in listitems){list1.addItem(listitems[i])}    
  var Textbox1 = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('TB1');
  var email = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('mail');
  var upLoad = app.createFileUpload().setName('uploadedFile');
  var submitButton = app.createSubmitButton('<B>Submit</B>'); 
  var warning = app.createHTML('Please fill in all fields').setStyleAttribute('background','#bbbbbb').setStyleAttribute('fontSize','18px');
  //file upload
  var cliHandler2 = app.createClientHandler()
  .validateLength(Textbox1, 1, 40).validateNotMatches(list1,'Select a category').validateEmail(email).validateNotMatches(upLoad, 'FileUpload')
  .forTargets(submitButton).setEnabled(true)
  .forTargets(warning).setHTML('Now you can submit your form').setStyleAttribute('background','#99FF99').setStyleAttribute('fontSize','12px');

  //Grid layout of items on form
  grid.setWidget(0, 1, title)
      .setText(1, 0, 'Category')
      .setWidget(1, 1, list1.addClickHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setText(2, 0, 'Name')
      .setWidget(2, 1, Textbox1.addClickHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setText(3, 0, 'Email')
      .setWidget(3, 1, email)
      .setText(4, 0, 'Image File')
      .setWidget(4, 1, upLoad.addChangeHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setWidget(5, 0, submitButton)
      .setWidget(5, 1, warning);

  var cliHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(warning).setHTML('<B>PLEASE WAIT WHILE THE FILE IS UPLOADING<B>').setStyleAttribute('background','yellow');
  submitButton.addClickHandler(cliHandler).setEnabled(false);  
  panel.add(grid);
  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}


function doPost(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var ListVal = e.parameter.list1;
  var textVal = e.parameter.TB1;
  var Email = e.parameter.mail;
  var fileBlob = e.parameter.uploadedFile;
  var blob = fileBlob.setContentTypeFromExtension()
  var img = DocsList.createFile(blob);
  try{
  var folder = DocsList.getFolder('photos');
  }catch(e){DocsList.createFolder('photos');var folder = DocsList.getFolder('photos')}
  img.addToFolder(folder);
  img.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder());
  var weight = parseInt(img.getSize()/1000);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(submissionSSKey).getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 4).setValues([[ListVal,textVal,Email,"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="+img.getId()]]);
  var imageInsert = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 5).setFormula('=image("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id='+img.getId()+'")');
  sheet.setRowHeight(lastRow+1, 80);
  var GDoc = DocumentApp.openByUrl(docurl)
  GDoc.appendTable([['Category : '+ListVal,'Name : '+textVal,'Email : '+Email]])
  var inlineI = GDoc.appendImage(img);
  var width = inlineI.getWidth();
  var newW = width;
  var height = inlineI.getHeight();
  var newH = height;
  var ratio = width/height;
  Logger.log('w='+width+'h='+height+' ratio='+ratio);
  if(width>640){
  newW = 640;
  newH = parseInt(newW/ratio);
  }
  inlineI.setWidth(newW).setHeight(newH)
  GDoc.appendParagraph('IMAGE size : '+width+' x '+height+' (eventually) resized to '+newW+' x '+newH+' for PREVIEW ('+weight+' kB)   ');
  GDoc.appendHorizontalRule();
  GDoc.saveAndClose();
  app.add(app.createLabel('Thank you for submitting'));
  return app
}
```

links  are the same : [app](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx1_5TIf3ndWudgLGPqs5-AHa-HUBe5qv5PWuInKzm52xHlq5l1/exec)   [SS](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnqSFd3iikE3dGFsUWNpb08zVWx5YjFRckloZ0NFZGc&usp=drive_web#gid=0)  [doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1E6yoROb52QjICsEbGVXIBdz8KhdFU_5gimWlJUbu8DI/edit)

Comment: Where should I embed this script? I tried to create new form and from Tools -> Add script I added these files, but somehow the script is never invoked. How to create form using this script?

Comment: Add Script == Script Editor

Comment: Unfortunatly UiApp deprecated since December 11, 2014

Answer (score 1):

To get a direct link to the image in the spreadsheet, use the `getID` function instead of `getUrl` and prepend the URL to `Gdrive`.

**Change this:**

```
var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 4)
    .setValues([[ListVal,textVal,Email,img.getUrl()]]);
```

**To this:**

```
var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 4)
   .setValues([[ListVal,textVal,Email,"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="+img.getId()]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** : I <strike>upgrade</strike> change the code a little bit, because as yyk mentionned, <strike>UiApp</strike> "doclist" deprecated since December 11, 2014. I use it to create a trombinoscope (i don't know the word in english, group gallery perhaps) in a google doc, people uploaded their picture nd name in a form. I don't use a spreadsheet. Here is the code :

```js
   function doGet(e) {
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Trombi');
var panel = app.createFormPanel();
var grid = app.createGrid(3,2).setId('registrationGrid');
var nameLabel = app.createLabel('Name');
var nameTextbox = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('Name');
var submitButton = app.createSubmitButton('<B>send</B>'); 
var warning = app.createHTML('<B>Please wait<B>').setStyleAttribute('background','yellow').setVisible(false)
//file upload
var upLoadTypeLabel = app.createLabel('File to Upload');
var upLoad = (app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile'));
//Grid layout of items on form
grid.setWidget(0, 0, nameLabel)
    .setWidget(0, 1, nameTextbox)
    .setWidget(1, 0, upLoadTypeLabel)
    .setWidget(1, 1, upLoad)
    .setWidget(2, 0, submitButton)
    .setWidget(2, 1, warning)
var cliHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(warning).setVisible(true)
submitButton.addClickHandler(cliHandler);  
panel.add(grid);
app.add(panel);
return app;}

function doPost(e) {
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();  
var Name = e.parameter.Name;
//app.getElementById('info').setVisible(true).setStyleAttribute('color','red');
 // data returned is a blob for FileUpload widget
var fileBlob = e.parameter.thefile;  
var doc = DriveApp.createFile(fileBlob).setName(Name); 
var doc = DocumentApp.openById('your key');
var body = doc.getBody();
var inlineI = body.appendImage(fileBlob);
  var width = inlineI.getWidth();
  var newW = width;
  var height = inlineI.getHeight();
  var newH = height;
  var ratio = width/height;
  Logger.log('w='+width+'h='+height+' ratio='+ratio);
  if(width>200){
  newW = 200;
  newH = parseInt(newW/ratio);
  }
  inlineI.setWidth(newW).setHeight(newH)
  body.appendParagraph(Name);
  body.appendHorizontalRule();
doc.saveAndClose();
app.add(app.createLabel('success')); 
return app
 }
```

Comment: ??  That's UiApp too ... What's the point to post that in April 2015 ? Je ne pense pas qu'on puisse traduire le mot trombinoscope... C'est typiquement un mot franco-français ça non ? ;-)

Comment: You're right Serge, it's UiApp too, sorry. But for some reason your code has stopped working ("Error encountered: An unexpected error occurred"). It worked very well until December, I have using it (by the way, thank you very much !). I think, but i'm not sure, that it's the "DocsList" service that is deprecated : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/sunset

et oui, tu as aussi raison, Trombinoscope est un mot franco-français, j'essayais juste de trouver une traduction approximative pour nos amis anglophones ;-)

Comment: I didn't find something to replace **Docslist**, so i'm not able to save the files in a specific folder, any idea ?

Comment: please avoid asking question in comments, start a new thread instead if necessary. btw, DriveApp has also a folder object that you can use to save files in.