# Create Google document with pictures and descriptions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am fairly new to Google Apps Script for something complex like this.  I am attempting this small project to investigate and improve my understand of Google Apps Script.  I have spent a lot of time off and on on this task.  I feel like I'm approaching this task all wrong and I need a some guidance.  BTW, the end user is my brother.

Overview:

The end user performs inspections and he takes pictures of issues that he discovered.  I would like to create a Google Apps solution that will allow the end user to upload the pictures, make notations, then generate a PDF report to print/email.  The solution would allow him to upload his pictures and make notations or provide descriptions.

Problems:

The pictures are high resolution pictures that can be about 5-6 Megabtyes each, but the final report usually does not need this high resolution of pictures.  I think I would need to reduce the picture resolution to an appropriate level for the reports.

I would like the end user to be able to perform all the tasks within the custom Google Apps Script workflow solution without having to jump to this, that, or the other application (like using Picasa).

Would I create a UiApp to create a form to use for uploading the pictures and making notations?

Thanks for all the help.  Just let me know if I need to provide any more clarification on my request.

Sincerely,

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461170/upload-an-image-to-a-google-spreadsheet/15474002#15474002) where I suggest a complete workflow to handle image upload with automatic resize.  You should only add a textArea widget to type the comments wich would be a good GAS practice exercise :-)

The post has a couple of links to online [demo form](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx1_5TIf3ndWudgLGPqs5-AHa-HUBe5qv5PWuInKzm52xHlq5l1/exec) , [doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1E6yoROb52QjICsEbGVXIBdz8KhdFU_5gimWlJUbu8DI/edit?usp=sharing) and [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnqSFd3iikE3dGFsUWNpb08zVWx5YjFRckloZ0NFZGc&usp=sharing), feel free to have a look, many people have already posted a lot of images of all kind !!

---

Following your comments - this script does not modify the original file, it would be possible to upload multiple files in one submission, Picasa is probably a good idea, have a look at this [tuto](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/picasa_google_apis) to see how to integrate it in gas, have a look also to Romain Vialard and James Ferreira website (easy to find in a google search)

Comment: The [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461170/upload-an-image-to-a-google-spreadsheet) you referenced appears it will be very helpful.  This is good for uploading one file at a time.  Do you know if there is a solution to upload 10, 15 or 20 files at once?  The function doPost(e) seems to resize the file in a Google Document.  Is the function re-sizing the original source image file on the Google Drive OR not?

Comment: I'm wondering if the images should be uploaded into the Google Drive or into a Google Picasa Album.  I know from working directly with Google Picasa, the Picasa tool can re-size the actual image making the image source size smaller, etc.  Any suggestions?