# Uploading images to a Google Spreadsheet using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I'm new to scripting. I have copied the code from here [Upload image to Google Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461170/upload-an-image-to-a-google-spreadsheet/15474002#15474002)

The original script allowed a user to upload 1 image via the web app form and then the image would append to a row in a Google spreadsheet and into a Google Doc. I have been able to modify the web app form to allow a user to upload 2 images, but I can't figure out how to get the second image into the spreadsheet and doc.

```
    var submissionSSKey = 'Google Spreadsheet key';
var docurl = 'Google document URL'
var listitems = ['Select a category','Portrait','Landscape','Other','Night shots','Nature','Various']
var Panelstyle = {'background':'#dddddd','padding':'40px','borderStyle':'solid','borderWidth':'10PX','borderColor':'#bbbbbb'}

function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Photography contest').setStyleAttribute('padding','50PX');
  var panel = app.createFormPanel().setStyleAttributes(Panelstyle).setPixelSize(400, 200);
  var title = app.createHTML('<B>Photography contest</B>').setStyleAttribute('color','grey').setStyleAttribute('fontSize','25PX');
  var grid = app.createGrid(7,2).setId('grid');
  var list1 = app.createListBox().setName('list1').setWidth('130');
   for(var i in listitems){list1.addItem(listitems[i])}    
  var Textbox1 = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('TB1');
  var email = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('mail');
  var upLoad = app.createFileUpload().setName('uploadedFile');
  var upLoad1 = app.createFileUpload().setName('uploadedFile1');
  var submitButton = app.createSubmitButton('<B>Submit</B>'); 
  var warning = app.createHTML('Please fill in all fields').setStyleAttribute('background','#bbbbbb').setStyleAttribute('fontSize','18px');
  //file upload
  var cliHandler2 = app.createClientHandler()
  .validateLength(Textbox1, 1, 40).validateNotMatches(list1,'Select a category').validateEmail(email).validateNotMatches(upLoad, 'FileUpload');


  var cliHandler3 = app.createClientHandler()
  .validateNotMatches(upLoad1, 'FileUpload').forTargets(submitButton).setEnabled(true)
  .forTargets(warning).setHTML('Now you can submit your form').setStyleAttribute('background','#99FF99').setStyleAttribute('fontsize','12px');

  //Grid layout of items on form
  grid.setWidget(0, 1, title)
      .setText(1, 0, 'Category')
      .setWidget(1, 1, list1.addClickHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setText(2, 0, 'Name')
      .setWidget(2, 1, Textbox1.addClickHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setText(3, 0, 'Email')
      .setWidget(3, 1, email)
      .setText(4, 0, 'Image File')
      .setWidget(4, 1, upLoad.addChangeHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setWidget(5, 1, upLoad1.addChangeHandler(cliHandler3))
      .setWidget(6, 0, submitButton)
      .setWidget(6, 1, warning);

  var cliHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(warning).setHTML('<B>PLEASE WAIT WHILE THE FILE IS UPLOADING<B>').setStyleAttribute('background','yellow');
  submitButton.addClickHandler(cliHandler).setEnabled(false);  
  panel.add(grid);
  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}


function doPost(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var ListVal = e.parameter.list1;
  var textVal = e.parameter.TB1;
  var Email = e.parameter.mail;
  var fileBlob = e.parameter.uploadedFile;
  var blob = fileBlob.setContentTypeFromExtension()
  var img = DocsList.createFile(blob);
  try{
  var folder = DocsList.getFolder('photos');
  }catch(e){DocsList.createFolder('photos');var folder = DocsList.getFolder('photos')}
  img.addToFolder(folder);
  img.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder());
  var weight = parseInt(img.getSize()/1000);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(submissionSSKey).getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 4).setValues([[ListVal,textVal,Email,"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="+img.getId()]]);
  var imageInsert = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 5).setFormula('=image("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id='+img.getId()+'")');
  sheet.setRowHeight(lastRow+1, 80);
  var GDoc = DocumentApp.openByUrl(docurl)
  GDoc.appendTable([['Category : '+ListVal,'Name : '+textVal,'Email : '+Email]])
  var inlineI = GDoc.appendImage(img);
  var width = inlineI.getWidth();
  var newW = width;
  var height = inlineI.getHeight();
  var newH = height;
  var ratio = width/height;


  var fileBlob1 = e.parameter.uploadedFile1;
  var blob1 = fileBlob1.setContentTypeFromExtension()
  var img1 = Doclist.createFile(blob1);
  try{
  var folder = DocsList.getFolder('photos');
  }catch(e){DocsList.createFolder('photos');var folder = DocsList.getFolder('photos')}
  img1.addToFolder(folder);
  img1.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder());
  var weight = parseInt(img1.getSize()/1000);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(submissionSSKey).getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 5).setValues([[ListVal,textVal,Email,"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="+img1.getId()]]);
  var imageInsert = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 6).setFormula('=image("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id='+img1.getId()+'")');
  sheet.setRowHeight(lastRow+1, 80);
  var GDoc = DocumentApp.openByUrl(docurl)
  GDoc.appendTable([['Category : '+ListVal,'Name : '+textVal,'Email : '+Email]])
  var inlineI = GDoc.appendImage(img1);
  var width = inlineI.getWidth();
  var newW = width;
  var height = inlineI.getHeight();
  var newH = height;
  var ratio = width/height;


  Logger.log('w='+width+'h='+height+' ratio='+ratio);
  if(width>640){
  newW = 640;
  newH = parseInt(newW/ratio);
  }
  inlineI.setWidth(newW).setHeight(newH)
  GDoc.appendParagraph('IMAGE size : '+width+' x '+height+' (eventually) resized to '+newW+' x '+newH+' for PREVIEW ('+weight+' kB)   ');
  GDoc.appendHorizontalRule();
  GDoc.saveAndClose();
  app.add(app.createLabel('Thank you for submitting'));
  return app
}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about deprecated Google Apps Script classes (Class UiApp, Class DocList)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I wrote the initial script I thought I had to help on this second version :-)

Here is the new doPost :

```
function doPost(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var ListVal = e.parameter.list1;
  var textVal = e.parameter.TB1;
  var Email = e.parameter.mail;
  var fileBlob1 = e.parameter.uploadedFile;
  var blob1 = fileBlob1.setContentTypeFromExtension()
  var img1 = DocsList.createFile(blob1);
  var fileBlob2 = e.parameter.uploadedFile1;
  var blob2 = fileBlob2.setContentTypeFromExtension()
  var img2 = DocsList.createFile(blob2);
  try{
  var folder = DocsList.getFolder('photos');
  }catch(e){DocsList.createFolder('photos');var folder = DocsList.getFolder('photos')}
  img1.addToFolder(folder);
  img1.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder());
  img2.addToFolder(folder);
  img2.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder());
  var weight1 = parseInt(img1.getSize()/1000);
  var weight2 = parseInt(img2.getSize()/1000);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(submissionSSKey).getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 5).setValues([[ListVal,textVal,Email,"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="+img1.getId(),"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="+img2.getId()]]);
  var image1Insert = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 6).setFormula('=image("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id='+img1.getId()+'")');
  var image2Insert = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 7).setFormula('=image("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id='+img2.getId()+'")');
  sheet.setRowHeight(lastRow+1, 80);
  var GDoc = DocumentApp.openByUrl(docurl)
  GDoc.appendTable([['Category : '+ListVal,'Name : '+textVal,'Email : '+Email]])
  var inlineI = GDoc.appendImage(img1);
  var width = inlineI.getWidth();
  var newW = width;
  var height = inlineI.getHeight();
  var newH = height;
  var ratio = width/height;
  Logger.log('w='+width+'h='+height+' ratio='+ratio);
  if(width>640){
  newW = 640;
  newH = parseInt(newW/ratio);
  }
  inlineI.setWidth(newW).setHeight(newH)
  GDoc.appendParagraph('IMAGE size : '+width+' x '+height+' (eventually) resized to '+newW+' x '+newH+' for PREVIEW ('+weight1+' kB)   ');
  var inlineI = GDoc.appendImage(img2);
  var width = inlineI.getWidth();
  var newW = width;
  var height = inlineI.getHeight();
  var newH = height;
  var ratio = width/height;
  Logger.log('w='+width+'h='+height+' ratio='+ratio);
  if(width>640){
  newW = 640;
  newH = parseInt(newW/ratio);
  }
  inlineI.setWidth(newW).setHeight(newH)
  GDoc.appendParagraph('IMAGE size : '+width+' x '+height+' (eventually) resized to '+newW+' x '+newH+' for PREVIEW ('+weight2+' kB)   ');
  GDoc.appendHorizontalRule();
  GDoc.saveAndClose();
  app.add(app.createLabel('Thank you for submitting'));
  return app
}
```

and the doGet with few modifications :

```
var submissionSSKey = '11nxqFSYCqrtF1ukfbuVAJy9bnBnxkLTH0dIAIRKxZxo';
var docurl = 'https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xEQC63NP4D6bebTVeP1u1nagvVm6vE2KFedRuk86VFc/edit'
var listitems = ['Select a category','Portrait','Landscape','Other','Night shots','Nature','Various']
var Panelstyle = {'background':'#dddddd','padding':'40px','borderStyle':'solid','borderWidth':'10PX','borderColor':'#bbbbbb'}

function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Photography contest').setStyleAttribute('padding','50PX');
  var panel = app.createFormPanel().setStyleAttributes(Panelstyle).setPixelSize(400, 200);
  var title = app.createHTML('<B>Photography contest</B>').setStyleAttribute('color','grey').setStyleAttribute('fontSize','25PX');
  var grid = app.createGrid(7,2).setId('grid');
  var list1 = app.createListBox().setName('list1').setWidth('130');
   for(var i in listitems){list1.addItem(listitems[i])}    
  var Textbox1 = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('TB1');
  var email = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('mail');
  var upLoad = app.createFileUpload().setName('uploadedFile');
  var upLoad1 = app.createFileUpload().setName('uploadedFile1');
  var submitButton = app.createSubmitButton('<B>Submit</B>'); 
  var warning = app.createHTML('Please fill in all fields').setStyleAttribute('background','#bbbbbb').setStyleAttribute('fontSize','18px');
  //file upload
  var cliHandler2 = app.createClientHandler()
  .validateLength(Textbox1, 1, 40).validateNotMatches(list1,'Select a category').validateEmail(email).validateNotMatches(upLoad, 'FileUpload');


  var cliHandler3 = app.createClientHandler()
  .validateNotMatches(upLoad1, 'FileUpload').forTargets(submitButton).setEnabled(true)
  .forTargets(warning).setHTML('Now you can submit your form').setStyleAttribute('background','#99FF99').setStyleAttribute('fontsize','12px');

  //Grid layout of items on form
  grid.setWidget(0, 1, title)
      .setText(1, 0, 'Category')
      .setWidget(1, 1, list1.addClickHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setText(2, 0, 'Name')
      .setWidget(2, 1, Textbox1.addClickHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setText(3, 0, 'Email')
      .setWidget(3, 1, email)
      .setText(4, 0, 'Image File')
      .setWidget(4, 1, upLoad.addChangeHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setWidget(5, 1, upLoad1.addChangeHandler(cliHandler3))
      .setWidget(6, 0, submitButton)
      .setWidget(6, 1, warning);

  var cliHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(warning).setHTML('<B>PLEASE WAIT WHILE THE FILE IS UPLOADING<B>').setStyleAttribute('background','yellow');
  submitButton.addClickHandler(cliHandler).setEnabled(false);  
  panel.add(grid);
  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}
```

Comment: Serge insas you are awesome!!! thank you!! One thing, I still get the #N/A "error: no image was found at url..." in the preview cells for the image. FYI: I'm doing this within a Google Apps Domain. Not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: I post the doGet also, I forgot I made small changes there too, sorry about that...

Comment: this works awesome!! you have made my week. Still the #N/A error for the image previews in the ss still there. Minor issue, I can use what you have supplied. Thanks again!

Comment: strange... I don't get the error in my testSheet... are the images in your drive ?

Comment: Yes. They are in the "Photos" folder, but I have to download them in order to open and view them. It's ok, I can use the ones in the Google document. Thanks @Serge insas.