# Google Sheets - Get File Name from Hard Drive and Insert into Sheet - (Emulate Excel's Appication.GetOpenFilename)

Tags: javascript, file, google-apps-script, google-sheets, filepicker

In Excel I can run a VBA script with `application.getopenfilename` and am able to place the filepath of the items selected into that cell.  I'm trying to convert my VBA

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

  If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("AG4:AG910")) Is Nothing Then
  Dim FileNames As Variant
  Dim Msg As String
  Dim i As Integer
  FileNames = Application.GetOpenFilename(MultiSelect:=True)
  If IsArray(FileNames) Then
      For i = LBound(FileNames) To UBound(FileNames)
          Msg = Msg & FileNames(i) & vbNewLine
      Next i
      Target = Msg
          Else
      MsgBox "No files were selected."
End If

End If
```

Basically I want to be be able to select images and then get the filenames. I only need the filenames because the clients send me the product pics which I have to then optimize before uploading.

Comment: Yeah, all I see for info is the GetName function in the Google Scripts Docs, but this only gives me a name reference for a sheet. Unfortunately I need the filename extracted from my local computer and placed into the Google Sheets active cell.

I did see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593249/uploading-images-to-a-google-spreadsheet-using-apps-script  but it uses an outside form so if theres a way to link a form option to a cell that'd be fine also

Comment: So, if you had a file picker, that you could use to select a file from your hard drive, and then get the file name without uploading the file, would that work for you?  (And have the file name get put into the Spreadsheet)

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do. In Excel the GetOpenFilename allows the file dialog box to execute and then the filename that is selected is placed in the cell

Comment: You'd need a custom menu, that then opened a Dialog Box or Sidebar with HTML in it.  Then the HTML would have a file picker.  That would get the name, and insert it into your Spreadsheet.  If that sounds okay, I can give an answer with how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This explanation shows:

- Automatic creation of Custom Menu Item
- Code to open Dialog box
- HTML and `<script>` tag in the HTML for the dialog box
- Code to put the result into the spreadsheet

### Code.gs - onOpen() - Create Custom Menu

```
function onOpen() {

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Show Upload Dialog', 'showUploadBox')
      .addToUi();
};
```

### gs Code - Open Dialog

```
function showUploadBox() {

  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Dialog')
     .setWidth(500)
     .setHeight(500);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Title of Dialog');
};
```

### Dialog Upload.html

Create a new file with this HTML

```
<div id="formDiv">

<form id="myForm">

    <input id="fileName" name="picToLoad" type="file" />
    <br>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="fncGetFileName()" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
    <input id="idBtnClose" type="button" value="Close" style="display: none" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
</form>
</div>

<br>
<br>

<div id="status" style="display: none">
  <!-- div will be filled with innerHTML after form submission. -->
  Working. Please wait...
</div>


<script>

function fncGetFileName(frmData) {
  console.log('fncGetFileName ran!');

  var theFileName = document.getElementById('fileName').value;
  theFileName = theFileName.slice(12);

  console.log('theFileName: ' + theFileName);

  document.getElementById('status').style.display = 'inline'; //Display msg

  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(updateOutput)
    .processForm(theFileName)
};
  // Javascript function called by "submit" button handler,
  // to show results.

  function updateOutput() {

    var outputDiv = document.getElementById('status');
    outputDiv.innerHTML = "The File Name was Written!";

    document.getElementById('idBtnClose').style.display = 'inline'; //Display msg
  }

</script>
```

### gs Code to Save File Name to Sheet

```
function processForm(argFileName) {
  Logger.log('argFileName: ' + argFileName);

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var theSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var theRange = theSheet.getRange("B4");
  theRange.setValue(argFileName);
};
```