# Submit an Image with Google Forms

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I've read through two other questions about uploading an image into Google Forms, but it's still not working for me, and I can't figure out what I'm getting wrong.
[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461170/upload-an-image-to-a-google-spreadsheet)
[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593249/uploading-images-to-a-google-spreadsheet-using-apps-script/21634971#21634971)

[Here's my sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GjxpOgViIajIvDaSTMB5MlYa0ZSxgGa0izQSNZB_cEU/edit?usp=sharing)

[Here's the form.](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzxku7oKWPg4UkEV7rTNafrHQZ4kHTgyIHhgqhzBmUWI2FkkrKB/exec)

Here's the script:

```
var submissionSSKey = '1GjxpOgViIajIvDaSTMB5MlYa0ZSxgGa0izQSNZB_cEU';
var docurl =     'https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bwbKztm311K7rdbrzfzLG6ACs8n4nd4LaJ67L3whsfs/'
var listitems = ['Select a category','Portrait','Landscape','Nude','Night shots','Nature','Various']
var Panelstyle = {'background':'#dddddd','padding':'40px','borderStyle':'solid','borderWidth':'10PX','borderColor':'#bbbbbb'}

function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Photography contest').setStyleAttribute('padding','50PX');
  var panel = app.createFormPanel().setStyleAttributes(Panelstyle).setPixelSize(400, 200);
  var title = app.createHTML('<B>Photography contest</B>').setStyleAttribute('color','grey').setStyleAttribute('fontSize','25PX');
  var grid = app.createGrid(6,2).setId('grid');
  var list1 = app.createListBox().setName('list1').setWidth('130');
   for(var i in listitems){list1.addItem(listitems[i])}    
  var Textbox1 = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('TB1');
  var email = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('mail');
  var upLoad = app.createFileUpload().setName('uploadedFile');
  var submitButton = app.createSubmitButton('<B>Submit</B>'); 
  var warning = app.createHTML('Please fill in all fields').setStyleAttribute('background','#bbbbbb').setStyleAttribute('fontSize','18px');
  //file upload
  var cliHandler2 = app.createClientHandler()
  .validateLength(Textbox1, 1, 40).validateNotMatches(list1,'Select a category').validateEmail(email).validateNotMatches(upLoad, 'FileUpload')
  .forTargets(submitButton).setEnabled(true)
  .forTargets(warning).setHTML('Now you can submit your form').setStyleAttribute('background','#99FF99').setStyleAttribute('fontSize','12px');

  //Grid layout of items on form
  grid.setWidget(0, 1, title)
  .setText(1, 0, 'Category')
  .setWidget(1, 1, list1.addClickHandler(cliHandler2))
  .setText(2, 0, 'Name')
  .setWidget(2, 1, Textbox1.addClickHandler(cliHandler2))
  .setText(3, 0, 'Email')
  .setWidget(3, 1, email)
  .setText(4, 0, 'Image File')
  .setWidget(4, 1, upLoad.addChangeHandler(cliHandler2))
  .setWidget(5, 0, submitButton)
  .setWidget(5, 1, warning);

  var cliHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(warning).setHTML('<B>PLEASE WAIT WHILE THE FILE IS UPLOADING<B>').setStyleAttribute('background','yellow');
  submitButton.addClickHandler(cliHandler).setEnabled(false);  
  panel.add(grid);
  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}


function doPost(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var ListVal = e.parameter.list1;
  var textVal = e.parameter.TB1;
  var Email = e.parameter.mail;
  var fileBlob = e.parameter.uploadedFile;
  var blob = fileBlob.setContentTypeFromExtension()
  var img = DocsList.createFile(blob);
  try{
  var folder = DocsList.getFolder('photos');
  }catch(e){DocsList.createFolder('photos');var folder = DocsList.getFolder('photos')}
  img.addToFolder(folder);
  img.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder());
  var weight = parseInt(img.getSize()/1000);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(submissionSSKey).getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 4).setValues([[ListVal,textVal,Email,"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="+img.getId()]]);
  var imageInsert = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 5).setFormula('=image("https://drive.google.com/uc?    export=view&id='+img.getId()+'")');
  sheet.setRowHeight(lastRow+1, 80);
  var GDoc = DocumentApp.openByUrl(docurl)
  GDoc.appendTable([['Category : '+ListVal,'Name : '+textVal,'Email : '+Email]])
  var inlineI = GDoc.appendImage(img);
  var width = inlineI.getWidth();
  var newW = width;
  var height = inlineI.getHeight();
  var newH = height;
  var ratio = width/height;
  Logger.log('w='+width+'h='+height+' ratio='+ratio);
  if(width>640){
  newW = 640;
 newH = parseInt(newW/ratio);
  }
  inlineI.setWidth(newW).setHeight(newH)
  GDoc.appendParagraph('IMAGE size : '+width+' x '+height+' (eventually) resized to '+newW+' x '+newH+' for PREVIEW ('+weight+' kB)   ');
  GDoc.appendHorizontalRule();
  GDoc.saveAndClose();
  app.add(app.createLabel('Thank you for submitting'));
  return app
}
```

Additionally, I don't need the functionality of the image being uploaded to a Doc (just the Sheet), but I WOULD like to know the basics of adding additional questions.

Comment: This answer may help:  [Link to SO answer - File Upload](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22980821/2946873)

Comment: @SandyGood that worked beautifully! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sandy's comment is right, it's probably a better idea to switch to HTML service rather than using a deprecated UiApp service  (although it is still working for now).
Anyway, the code you show uses DocsList and this one is really dead ;-)

below is an updated code, keep your first lines with IDs and simply pste over the rest of it.

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Photography contest').setStyleAttribute('padding','50PX');
  var panel = app.createFormPanel().setStyleAttributes(Panelstyle).setPixelSize(400, 200);
  var title = app.createHTML('<B>Photography contest</B>').setStyleAttribute('color','grey').setStyleAttribute('fontSize','25PX');
  var grid = app.createGrid(7,2).setId('grid');
  var list1 = app.createListBox().setName('list1').setWidth('130');
   for(var i in listitems){list1.addItem(listitems[i])}    
  var Textbox1 = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('TB1');
  var email = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('mail');
  var upLoad = app.createFileUpload().setName('uploadedFile');
  var upLoad1 = app.createFileUpload().setName('uploadedFile1');
  var submitButton = app.createSubmitButton('<B>Submit</B>'); 
  var warning = app.createHTML('Please fill in all fields').setStyleAttribute('background','#bbbbbb').setStyleAttribute('fontSize','18px');
  //file upload
  var cliHandler2 = app.createClientHandler()
  .validateLength(Textbox1, 1, 40).validateNotMatches(list1,'Select a category').validateEmail(email).validateNotMatches(upLoad, 'FileUpload');


  var cliHandler3 = app.createClientHandler()
  .validateNotMatches(upLoad1, 'FileUpload').forTargets(submitButton).setEnabled(true)
  .forTargets(warning).setHTML('Now you can submit your form').setStyleAttribute('background','#99FF99').setStyleAttribute('fontsize','12px');

  //Grid layout of items on form
  grid.setWidget(0, 1, title)
      .setText(1, 0, 'Category')
      .setWidget(1, 1, list1.addClickHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setText(2, 0, 'Name')
      .setWidget(2, 1, Textbox1.addClickHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setText(3, 0, 'Email')
      .setWidget(3, 1, email)
      .setText(4, 0, 'Image File')
      .setWidget(4, 1, upLoad.addChangeHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setWidget(5, 1, upLoad1.addChangeHandler(cliHandler3))
      .setWidget(6, 0, submitButton)
      .setWidget(6, 1, warning);

  var cliHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(warning).setHTML('<B>PLEASE WAIT WHILE THE FILE IS UPLOADING<B>').setStyleAttribute('background','yellow');
  submitButton.addClickHandler(cliHandler).setEnabled(false);  
  panel.add(grid);
  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}


function doPost(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  var ListVal = e.parameter.list1;
  var textVal = e.parameter.TB1;
  var Email = e.parameter.mail;
  var fileBlob1 = e.parameter.uploadedFile;
  var blob1 = fileBlob1.setContentTypeFromExtension()
  var img1 = DriveApp.createFile(blob1);
  var fileBlob2 = e.parameter.uploadedFile1;
  var blob2 = fileBlob2.setContentTypeFromExtension()
  var img2 = DriveApp.createFile(blob2);
  try{
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('photos').next();
  }catch(e){DriveApp.createFolder('photos');var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('photos').next()}
  folder.addFile(img1);
  DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(img1);
  folder.addFile(img2);
  DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(img2);
  var weight1 = parseInt(img1.getSize()/1000);
  var weight2 = parseInt(img2.getSize()/1000);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(submissionSSKey).getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 5).setValues([[ListVal,textVal,Email,"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="+img1.getId(),"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="+img2.getId()]]);
  var image1Insert = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 6).setFormula('=image("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id='+img1.getId()+'")');
  var image2Insert = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 7).setFormula('=image("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id='+img2.getId()+'")');
  sheet.setRowHeight(lastRow+1, 80);
  var GDoc = DocumentApp.openByUrl(docurl)
  GDoc.appendTable([['Category : '+ListVal,'Name : '+textVal,'Email : '+Email]])
  var inlineI = GDoc.appendImage(img1);
  var width = inlineI.getWidth();
  var newW = width;
  var height = inlineI.getHeight();
  var newH = height;
  var ratio = width/height;
  Logger.log('w='+width+'h='+height+' ratio='+ratio);
  if(width>640){
  newW = 640;
  newH = parseInt(newW/ratio);
  }
  inlineI.setWidth(newW).setHeight(newH)
  GDoc.appendParagraph('IMAGE size : '+width+' x '+height+' (eventually) resized to '+newW+' x '+newH+' for PREVIEW ('+weight1+' kB)   ');
  var inlineI = GDoc.appendImage(img2);
  var width = inlineI.getWidth();
  var newW = width;
  var height = inlineI.getHeight();
  var newH = height;
  var ratio = width/height;
  Logger.log('w='+width+'h='+height+' ratio='+ratio);
  if(width>640){
  newW = 640;
  newH = parseInt(newW/ratio);
  }
  inlineI.setWidth(newW).setHeight(newH)
  GDoc.appendParagraph('IMAGE size : '+width+' x '+height+' (eventually) resized to '+newW+' x '+newH+' for PREVIEW ('+weight2+' kB)   ');
  GDoc.appendHorizontalRule();
  GDoc.saveAndClose();
  app.add(app.createLabel('Thank you for submitting'));
  return app
}
```