# Google app script: Send mail, inlineImage from js File

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications

I use **google.script.run** to use the **MailApp API** in google app script and I pass a mail object like this :

```
google.script.run.sendMail(mail);
```

The mail object is structured like this :

```
  var mail = {
    to:"",
    cc:"",
    subject:"",
    htmlBody:"",
    inlineImages: inlineImages
  }
```

*inlineImages* is a Javascript object that map **key string** to **image data (BlobSource)** from [google ressources](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app)

But then I pass *File* object in *inlineImages* I get **Failed due to illegal value**.

**EDIT :**

I get the *inlineImages* like this :

```
var inlineImages

function createImages(event) {
    var file = event.target.files[0];
    var key = "image"+Object.keys(inlineImages).length;

    inlineImages[key] = file;
}
```

I also try to get Image object :

```
function createImages(event) {
    var file = event.target.files[0];
    var key = "image"+Object.keys(inlineImages).length;

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = e.target.result;

        inlineImages[key] = img;
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

Comment: Could you show us how you get the `inlineImages` object please. And what's inside Thanks

Comment: @JSmith Edit done. Anyway I am actually uploading the images on the drive and then use the ID to get image URL, it's way more easy.

Comment: not sure to well undestand the whole process but is your final object like so `inlineImages: {variableName: imageObject}`??

Comment: Yep, I have the object mapping image with `inlineImages{key: FileObject}` every File have name, last update, ... properties.

Comment: what is exactly the event object in creatImages how o you trigger this function?

Comment: Trigger with `document.getElementById('importImage').addEventListener('change', createImage, false);` where *importImage* is the ID of an input

Comment: The thing is I'm not quite sure even if I don't use `blob`that often that the `blob` requested by  `inlineImages` is the same as the one you try to pass.

Comment: I think so, but google don't explain that much ... I will stay on URL for my img. Possible answer : `reader.onloadend = function(e) {
    inlineImages['test'] = e.target.result;`}

Comment: try reaing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41994351/how-do-i-convert-jpg-or-png-to-blob-on-google-app-script) maybe it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FileObject` is not a legal value.

> Legal parameters and return values are JavaScript primitives like a
>   + Number,
>   + Boolean,
>   + String, or
>   + null, as well as
>   + JavaScript objects and arrays that are composed of primitives, objects and arrays.
>   + A form element within the page is also legal as a parameter, but it must be the function’s only parameter, and it is not legal as a return value

The only way you're going to get a file past through the above restrictions from client to server are if you convert the fileObject to one of the above types. I'll go with form:

> If you call a server function with a form element as a parameter, the form becomes a single object with field names as keys and field values as values. The values are all converted to strings, except for the contents of **file-input fields**, which become **Blob** objects.

- [Bottleneck legal values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values)
- [Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms)

Comment: Yep, in fact `reader.onloadend = function(e) { inlineImages['test'] = e.target.result;}` where *e.target.result* is the file in string format (with file name, type and other info). Thanks for this I will check it for mail attachement