# gs upload file is corrupted

Tags: google-apps-script, file-upload, web-applications

I'm using Google Script App to upload the file on the form. Suddenly, the uploaded logic stop working.The uploaded files are corrupted and twice size as original file.

Here the code samples:

```
<input id="applicantPhoto" class="upload-file-field" type="file" name="applicantPhoto">
```

GS:

```
var folder = DriveApp.createFolder("MyUploadFolder);
var blob = form.applicantPhoto; 
var file = folder.createFile(blob);
```

The headers of the files are different.
The broken uploaded jpg file's header: ���� JFIF      ��
Original jpg file: ÿØÿà JFIF      ÿâ

Comment: Have you [searched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script+file-upload+google-apps-script-web-application?sort=newest) for similar problems first? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moving google apps script to v8 file upload stopped working from sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60742695/moving-google-apps-script-to-v8-file-upload-stopped-working-from-sidebar)

Comment: Thank you, V8 caused this problem. I disabled this option and the uploads are working again.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150675170

Make sure to use Rhino JavaScript interpreter: Run->Disable new Apps Script runtime powered by Chrome V8.