# Uploading mp3 file to Google Drive from Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Apps Script web app which I use to save form responses in a spreadsheet and Google drive.

One of the form fields saves a file in Google Drive, but it's not working.

**HTML form** (I have reduced it due to the form size)

```
<form id="miformulario" onsubmit="envio_formulario(this)">
  <input type="text" id="padre" name="padre" maxlength=8 value="" required class="form-control"/>
  <input type="email" id="mailp" name="mailp" value="" required class="form-control" />
  <input type="file" name="documentacion" >
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Tramitar solicitud</button>       
</form>
```

**form.js**

```
function envio_formulario(Objetoformulario) 
 {
   var values = $('#miformulario').serializeArray();

   var data = {};
   $(values ).each(function(index, obj){
     data[obj.name] = obj.value;
   });


    var invalid = Objetoformulario.querySelectorAll(':invalid');   

    if ( invalid.length == 0 ) // Si no hay errores grabamos los datos
     {

     const file = Objetoformulario.documentacion.files[0];
     const fr = new FileReader();    

     fr.onload = function(e) {
       const obj = {
         mimeType: file.type,
         bytes: [...new Int8Array(e.target.result)]
       };

     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(ficherocargado).cargarFichero(obj, data);

     };
     fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

   }            
}
```

**Code.gs**

```
function cargarFichero(file, form){

  console.log(file.mimeType); //Output => audio/mpeg
  console.log(typeof file.bytes); //Output => Object
  console.log(file.bytes);  //Output => [ 82, 73, 70, 70, -128.......]

  var fichero = Utilities.newBlob(file.bytes, file.mimeType, "file");
  console.log(fichero)  // Output => undefined

  if (fichero){

    var documentosI = "xxxxxx";  
    var documentosII = cif + "_" + cliente;
    var carpetaI, carpetasI = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(documentosI);
    var carpetaII, carpetasII = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(documentosII);

    if (carpetasI.hasNext()) {
      carpetaI = carpetasI.next();      
    }  

    if (carpetasII.hasNext()) {
      carpetaII = carpetasII.next();      
    } 
    else {
      carpetaII = carpetaI.createFolder(documentosII);
    } 

    var documentacion = carpetaII.createFile(fichero);
    documentacion.setName(cif + " _ " + cliente + " _ ATEN");  
    var id_documento = documentacion.getId();
  } 
}
```

[image]

The data is being sended properly to code.gs, in the server function I receive the file.bytes and the file.mimeType but when I try to create the [newBlob](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#newblobdata,-contenttype_1) it doesn't create anything, returns as undefined. Any thoughts?

Comment: In the method `newBlob(data, contentType)` data should be a byte array. And in `newBlob(data, contentType, name)` data should be string according to the documentation. I think you are using byte size. Forgive me if I am wrong. I don't understand pure JavaScript as in the first file. I am talking about the second file only.

Comment: The 1-st argument of newBlob(...) should be **the string for the blob, assumed UTF-8**. `file.bytes` in your code is not a string. Moreover, `cargafichero(...)` arguments have restricted data types too. See [google.script.run manual](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#index.html) for details.

Comment: @TylerRake i had an error in the code. The data object (file.bytes) was a byte array, the output (300000) was the file.bytes.length. I'm sorry, i've updated the question, it's still not working...

Comment: @АлександрЕрмолин thanks. I had an error in the code explanation, the 1-st argument of newBlob output was actually the byte size (file.bytes.length). I've checked the google.script.run restrictions, but i think that i'm not breaking any of them...

Comment: Can you show the output of `file.type` and `file.bytes`?

Comment: @ziganotschka i've added a photo with the logs of file.mimeType, typeof file.bytes and file.bytes

Comment: Can you call the function `cargarFichero` at all? Jut asking because of the typing mistake in `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(ficherocargado).cargafichero(obj, data);`

Comment: @ziganotschka yes I'm calling the server function properly, I wrote the function name wrongly here in stackoverflow but in the actual code it's fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. I was trying to store the newBlob in the variable "fichero", and after that i done a console.log() to view the content. It returns undefined, and i really tought it wasn't working, but it worked all the time.

I had a conditional to check if the file existed, because the client form didn't always have a file. Here I upload the file to Google Drive:

```
if (fichero){
  ......
  carpetaII.createFile(fichero); //Store in Google Drive
}
```

The "fichero" variable was returning undefined, so i never had the option to store the file in Google Drive.

So I changed `if (fichero){}` to `if (file.bytes){}` and now it works properly.