# Google apps script upload file doesn't work

Tags: google-apps-script

Morning, i'm trying to upload file to my drive by my website with the following script:
 Code.gs:

```
 function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index")
}


function uploadFiles(data)
{
 var file = data.image
 var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('images_audios')
 var createFile = folder.createFile(file)
 return createFile.getId()
}
```

And for index.html

```
    <html>
<body>
<form>
   <input type="file" name="image">
   <input type="button" onclick="google.script.run.uploadFiles(this.parentNode)" value="Upload" >
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The file is created but empty, unreadable. No matter the file i use, he is always empty, i don't know why. please help me.

Comment: I think that this thread is useful for resolving your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/q/60742695/7108653

Comment: It's working, thank you Sir !

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.