# ScriptError: We're sorry, a server error occured. Please wait a bit and try again

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, file-upload, web-applications, server-error

I keep getting

> ScriptError: We're sorry, a server error occured. Please wait a bit and try again.

whenever I try to run the following code:

### macros.gs

```
/**   @OnlyCurrentDoc   */
// When the Sheet is opened, add the menu and create an item in the menu *** WORKING
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Menu')
      .addItem('Send Confirmation Email', 'createSideBar')
      .addToUi();
}


// Creates the side bar from the Index.html file and displays it *** WORKING
function createSideBar() {
  var form = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate().setTitle('Send Confirmation Email');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(form);
}


// Test function where I make a request to my site *** NOT WORKING
function testerr(formObject) {
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://webhook.site/...');
  return "Complete!";
}
```

### Form.html

```
<form id="sendEmailForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="row_number">Row</label>
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="number" id="row_number" name="row_number" required>
    </div>

    <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="images_input" name="images_input" multiple required>
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="images_input">Select images...</label>
    </div> 

    <button id="submit-btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-block">Submit</button>

</form>
```

### JavaScript.html

```
<script>
    // Prevent forms from submitting. *** WORKING
    function preventFormSubmit() {
        console.log('Entered preventFormSubmit()...');
        
        var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
        for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
            forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        }
        
        console.log('Exited preventFormSubmit()...');
    }
    window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit); // *** WORKING

    // *** NOT WORKING
    function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
        console.log('Entered handleFormSubmit()...');
        
        google.script.run.withFailureHandler(updateButton).testerr(formObject);
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateButton).testerr(formObject);
        
        console.log('Exited handleFormSubmit()...');
    }

    // *** WORKING
    function updateButton(str) {
        document.getElementById('submit-btn').innerHTML = str;
    }
</script>
```

I simply want to create sidebar form that when submitted will make a request to a site. The only issue is when you click on submit, the ScriptError will show up. I've pinpointed where the error is being thrown: when `handleFormSubmit()` is called after hitting submit, this line `google.script.run.withFailureHandler(updateButton).testerr(formObject)` causes the error to be thrown.

I tried commenting all the lines out in the `testerr()` function and replacing them with a simple `return "Complete!";` line. Still, the error persists.

Why is this happening? I can't figure out why, any help is appreciated!

Comment: What runtime are you using? Have you signed in a single Google account or in multiple accounts? Why are you calling `macros.gs` to your server-side code file?

Comment: V8 Runtime. Single Google account. I don't get your last question.

Comment: The default file uses `Code.gs` or a variant according the Google account language, `macros.gs` is a file name used for Google Sheets macros... since the V8 runtime is buggy, maybe using that filename could cause some problems. In order tor reproduce the problem it will be nice to know if you set the name manually or you are using a file created automatically as this affects the project manifest.

Comment: @Rubén I just changed the name of the file from `macros.gs` to `Code.gs` and it still doesn't work. I followed the steps from here if it helps: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms

Comment: Try removing the `input type="file"`

Comment: Also try changing to the old runtime

Comment: @Rubén OK so it worked when I commented out the `input type="file"` part! I'll try switching to the old runtime and keeping the `input type="file"` to see if this is a bug with V8.

Comment: I added couple of links to my answer that might be helpful

Comment: @Rubén yeap, switching to the old runtime fixed the issue. Thank you so much you saved me hours of mindless debugging!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will solve "all" the problems with your code, but...

Replace

```
google.script.run.withFailureHandler(updateButton).testerr(formObject);
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateButton).testerr(formObject);
```

by

```
google.script.run
.withFailureHandler(updateButton)
.withSuccessHandler(updateButton)
.testerr(formObject);
```

The above because the original code is making two calls to the same server function. This could introduce some problems due to a "race condition" (any of the lines could finish before the other, and both will call the same client-side callback)

---

Maybe the combination of the new runtime(v8) and the use of `input file="type"` is causing problems. Try changing to the old runtime.

Related

- [Moving google apps script to v8 file upload stopped working from sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60742695/1595451)
- [google.script.run fails in case of file input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61931812/1595451)

Comment: Still doesn't work. In fact once I can get this thing to work, I'll only want to do `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateButton).testerr(formObject)` (no need for the failure handler). I only added the failure handler to try to figure out what was wrong!

Answer (score 1):

**Unfortunately, it seems that the issue you are encountering might be a bug.**

What you can do in this case is to **star** the issue on **Issue Tracker** [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149980602) by clicking the **★** next to the issue number and post a comment as well saying that you are affected by the issue.

As a workaround, you can try and switch back to the old runtime.

Comment: Is there supposed to be a link?