# How to capture uploaded file in post request to Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, file-upload, google-apps

I am trying to build a script to save data (text + image + pdf) from an HTML form (NOT Google Form).

I have the following function to upload a file:

```
function upload(x) {
  var destination_id = 'folder_id'
  var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById(destination_id)
  
  var contentType = 'image/png'
  var img = x.getAs(contentType)
  destination.createFile(img)
}
```

Inside my `doPost` function I am calling the above upload function like this:

```
upload(e.parameter.img)
```

I have an input of type `file` with a name and id of `img`. I also have the following event listener to prepare the body of the POST request:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
      e.preventDefault()
      let fd = new FormData(form)
      
      fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: fd})
        .then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
        .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
    })
```

When I submit my form, my text gets saved, but the file is not uploaded. I do not see any errors in the console either. What am I doing wrong? Is there an easier alternative to uploading form data to Google Drive?

Comment: I think you're not retrieving the data correctly on the web app side. `e.parameter.img` would be taking the data from the url parameter `img`, for example it would be equal to the string `sometext` for the url `https://script.google.com/a/domain/macros/s/XXXXXXXXXXXX/exec?img=sometext`. The post data should be in `e.parameters.data` but you will need to decode it using `Utilities.base64Decode(e.parameters.data)`. Can you confirm this?

Comment: You can see a list of the request parameters [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters)

Comment: @RafaGuillermo so the line would be `upload(Utilities.base64Decode(e.parameters.img[0]))` ? Since `e.parameters` returns arrays of values?

Comment: I think that `e.parameters.img` will be empty looking at your code snippets. Can you Log the contents of `e` and paste it?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo Update: It's still the same. In chrome dev tools, Network tab, Form Data shows `img: (binary)`. So I think the file is being passed to the backend.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo This is very silly of me. Could you please tell me how to log the contents of `e`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217394/discussion-between-rafa-guillermo-and-minigunnr).

Answer (score 2):

`type=file` don't seem to be currently supported. You can workaround this using `FileReader` api on the client side to convert file data to a base64 encoded websafe string and send the data as `string` or a byte array.

[Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60748334/)

Comment: Is there a tutorial that you might suggest for handling file uploads with FileReader API?

Comment: @MiniGunnR The related answer link is a excellent sample. Only reason I didn't close this question as a duplicate is because that client is Google web-app and your client is a different web app. Regardless the script should be almost the same, except the `google.script.run` part must be changed to `fetch`