# Upload file using Google Apps Script and html

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I cannot open the uploaded file and I strictly follow Google Guide's instruction:

[Google Guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms)

which are

```
//under Basic interact.gs

  function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function processForm(formObject) {
  var formBlob = formObject.myFile;
  var driveFile = DriveApp.createFile(formBlob);
  return driveFile.getUrl();
}
```

AND

```
//under index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      // Prevent forms from submitting.
      function preventFormSubmit() {
        var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
        for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
          forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
          });
        }
      }
      window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);

      function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateUrl).processForm(formObject);
      }
      function updateUrl(url) {
        var div = document.getElementById('output');
        div.innerHTML = '<a href="' + url + '">Got it!</a>';
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
      <input name="myFile" type="file" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <div id="output"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I can upload the file (say photo.jpg with 5kb)  using the index.html.
After the uploading, I could find (photo.jpg with 8kb) in https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive.
However, I cannot open the file (photo.jpg with 8kb) by previewing in Google Drive or by opening the file after downloading. (Error message: Paint cannot read this file. This is not a valid bitmap file, or its format is not currently supported)

The same problem when I tried a docx file. (Before upload: 45kb) (After upload: 79kb) (Error message#1: Word found unreadable content. Do you want to recover the contents of this document?)(After pressing Yes: Word experienced an error trying to open the file. Try these suggestions. Blablabla)

I do not know what to do next when I strictly follow the Google Guide.

Please help me..I am new to everything.Thank you.

And sorry for my poor english T^T

Comment: I think that this might be the answer for your question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/60742695 And also, this Javascript library might be useful. https://github.com/tanaikech/HtmlFormObjectParserForGoogleAppsScript_js#sample-script-3

Comment: It works well after I uncheck "Enable Chrom V8 tuntime" in Project Settings of GAS.
Thank you so much!!!! Tanaike