# How to make a form responsive by google app script and css

Tags: css, google-apps-script, responsive-design, google-sheets, multipartform-data

I have implemented upload from [Upload an image to a Google spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461170/upload-an-image-to-a-google-spreadsheet) link. But i cannot make it responsive and custom design.Is there any way to use css in above example for making it responsive??

Comment: You could use something like bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make the actual google spreadsheet more responsive, but you can build a HTML page (with css), with the tool editor. This can allow you to use the spreadsheet to your liking.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15474002/5010090 i want to make this example responsive..